# How can I obtain a Dynamic Bool that corresponds to the mouse being over a certain element?

Tags: haskell, reflex-dom

Suppose I have a button and a square, like this:

```
main = mainWidget $ do
    x <- button "Change color."
    y <- toggle False x
    z <- mapDyn style y
    elDynAttr "div" z blank

style :: Bool -> Map String String
style b | b         = "style" =: "height: 10ex; width: 10ex; background-color: #f00;"
        | otherwise = "style" =: "height: 10ex; width: 10ex; background-color: #900;"
```

The colour of the square will alternate between bright and dark red when the button is pressed.

I want to replace the button with a green rectangle in such a way that, when mouse pointer is over it, the red square is bright, otherwise dark. For bonus points, I would like the green rectangle to be a `div tabindex=0` and to make sure the red square is bright when it has focus, but, once I understand the general approach, I will likely be able to figure that out by myself.

My guess is that there is some API that allows adding event handlers to `el`, but I did not find one so far. And maybe there is a different approch altogether, that I could not know?

Answer (score 1):

The stuff you need is all found in [`Reflex.Dom.Widget.Basic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-dom-0.3/docs/Reflex-Dom-Widget-Basic.html). If you create a widget with a function that has a prime in its name, such as `el'`, you can get a hold of an object of type `El`, which is a member of `HasDomEvent`. `domEvent`, the only method of this class, lets you extract an event stream corresponding to one of a selection of event names. Mixing the events together and converting them to an appropriate `Dynamic` is then done with some usual Reflex tooling found in [`Reflex.Class`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.4.0.1/docs/Reflex-Class.html) and [`Reflex.Dynamic`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/reflex-0.4.0.1/docs/Reflex-Dynamic.html). You do need to familiarize yourself with these interfaces, but there is a helpful [quick reference](https://github.com/reflex-frp/reflex/blob/0.4/Quickref.md).

*(Make sure to use the documentation matching the version of Reflex you build against, as there are significant changes between versions.)*

One way to encode your case is as follows:

```
main = mainWidget $ do
    y <- greenBox
    z <- mapDyn style y
    elDynAttr "div" z blank

style :: Bool -> Map String String
style ...  -- Abridged for brevity.

greenBox :: MonadWidget t m => m (Dynamic t Bool)
greenBox = do
    (e, _) <- elAttr' "div" ("style" =: "height: 10ex; width: 10ex; background-color: #0c0;") blank
    let
        eEnter = domEvent Mouseenter e
        eLeave = domEvent Mouseleave e
    holdDyn False . leftmost $ [True <$ eEnter, False <$ eLeave]
```

What we do here is create a widget for the green box that returns a Dynamic indicating whether it is "activated". Everything else is just as it were in your initial example.

Thanks to [/u/dalaing](https://www.reddit.com/user/dalaing) for [advising me](https://www.reddit.com/r/reflexfrp/comments/8cfkjv/how_can_i_obtain_a_dynamic_bool_that_corresponds/dxfdff5/) on this.